# How to use some gradle librarys which have same attribute name in an app in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have import some gradle library in my app.But some of them have same attribute name like `<attr name="border_color" format="color" />` "border_color", so when I use gradle build to build the project I will get a merge error.So is there anyway to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Try to add exclude option in the gradle like this

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'values/attr.xml'
}
```

Not sure, but you can try